# How to make bootstrap responsive layout that does not stack all the content in single column?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I am a very new to front-end development so please bear it with me. Hopefully, I can use the right terms to describe the problem I am trying to solve. I've started using Twitter's bootstrap framework recently and I am trying to figure out if one can have the following fluid layout:

Say, this is the main layout, a row with 4 span3s.

1111 3333  2222 4444

When the screen is resized, the columns in that row stack-up in a single column as following:

1111

3333

2222

4444

And what I am trying to figure out is, if it is possible to stack those up in this manner if there is enough screen size:

1111 3333

2222 4444

And then if the screen size becomes really small then do a single column stack as mentioned above:

1111

3333

2222

4444

Thanks.

Comment: technically perfectly possible, but not with default TB styles however. With TB it is eather stacked or side by side, nothing in between. You will have to write your own media queries to achieve this...

Comment: Create your own rules to modify the width?

Comment: [Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/6342) (still in development, but soon will be released) will allow you to do so. Also, [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) already has such feature. Maybe you want to check out one of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a media query like this to override Bootstrap's default width on `.span3`. Bootstrap normally changes `span*` to 100% width when the screen is 768px or less.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  .span3 {
    width:41%;
  }
  .span3:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

You may need to tweak the margins and width accordingly.

<kbd>[**Demo on Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/66831)</kbd>

Comment: Love the demo on Bootply--didn't realize that site existed; though I've used jsFiddle quite a bit, this looks much more streamlined for TB.  I'll definitely have to make use of it!

Comment: Also, just to note, the :nth-child(3) selector only works on browsers that support CSS3 so if you have to support older versions of IE then you may need to use jQuery or some hard-coded class attributes in your HTML to achieve the effect, if you go this route.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Thanks for this answer and other useful comments. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

When you download Bootstrap from their home page (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/, instead of via their Customize page or via the GitHub project) it has the responsive styles separated into its own file.  You can then tweak/override the media queries (@media ...) to achieve what you're after without having to mess with the other Bootstrap baseline styles.  As one of your commenters mentioned, what you're describing is not out-of-the-box for TB, but it's not too difficult to achieve.

I'd suggest floating the spans to the left with a display of inline-block (might use the *display: inline; *zoom: 1; hack for IE7 if support is needed) for certain media queries to get them to fall as described.